# Using DB2 Sequence in Java Prepared Statement

Tags: java, jdbc, db2

I want to get the next value of a `db2` sequence if the placeholder in the preparedstatement is `0` . How can i do that .

```
PreparedStmt.setLong(1, attributeID);
```

So here if `attributeID` is `0`, i want to get the next value from the sequence, other wise i use the attribute ID .

I tried using

```
PreparedStmt.setObject(1, attributeID > 0 ? attributeID : next val for my seq);
```

but this does not work !

Comment: ...if you're trying to take care of the case where a new record is being inserted, usually you don't set the parameter to anything (leave it null).  Otherwise, I'm a little concerned that you're allowed to specify a new value for something (you may run into conflicts).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's to easy, just get the sequence like you get a result set with executeQuery() method. Then the select statement is:

```
SELECT SEQ_NAME.NEXTVAL FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
```

The other part is an if sentence. That's all you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare the primary key column as

```
ATTRIBUTEID BIGINT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY
```

To insert a row with a specific value, **include** the primary key column in the sql and set its value with:

```
PreparedStmt.setLong(1, attributeID);
```

To insert a row where database generates a value for key, omit the primary key column in the sql and do not set its value in the prepared statement.